# Azure Application Gateway SSL setup

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-application-gateway

I have a backend pool with two virtual machines and an application gateway for it. I would like to set a domain name with ssl support and certificate. I convert my .crt file to pfx and it's ok. When I go to the page I get 502 error message (Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.) because the health check is failed at 443 port.

How can I set the probe for HTTPS?

The certificate is not work because the health check and the health check probe doesn't work because certificate?

(Which came first, the chicken or the egg?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Azure Application Gateway probes backend servers to check their health status and to check whether they're ready to serve requests. You can use the default health probe or custom probe. So you should [check the backend health](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#how-to-check-backend-health) first. if the backend health for all the servers in a backend pool is `unhealthy` or `unknown`, you might encounter problems when you try to access applications.

> The default probe request is sent in the format of
>   ://127.0.0.1:/. For example, http://127.0.0.1:80 for
>   an http probe on port 80. Only HTTP status codes of 200 through 399
>   are considered healthy. The protocol and destination port are
>   inherited from the HTTP settings.

In this case, you could set the probe for HTTPS like `https://<host>:443/path`. For the host, you could check the box of `Pick host name from backend HTTP settings` or not. You also could set the probe to specify a path and recognize a different status code as Healthy.

If the health check is failed at 443 port, not sure the detailed error message on your side, probably it might be that the Application Gateway instances could not reach the backend server on the TCP port 443. You could try these solutions in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#tcp-connect-error).

[image]

For more information, you could refer to [troubleshooting bad gateway errors in Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502).

Please let me know if this works or show your detailed error message for further help.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works. I have to setup the same certificate for gateway and backend. The problem was I use different certificate for probe (dns resolve other server ip than my VM) and for gateway, because want to test my configuration before I make it live.

Comment: Glad it works, I upvote your comment. If my reply has helped you, Could you accept this answer(tick the box under the upvote )? It will benefit other members to easily find the same scenario.

Comment: Thank you for upvote. You are absolutely right, I ticked it.